# How to get Dynamics 365 Token?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dynamics-365

I trying to get Dynamics 365 token but the method for obtain the token is asynchronous and when I try to return the token I obtain a 500 Internal Server Error. Is there another way to get Dynamics 365 token? Or how can I show the token on return of the controller?

My get token method:

```
 public static async Task<string> AccessTokenGenerator()
    {
        string clientId = "myClientId";
        string clientSecret = "myClientSecret";
        string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/9dfdf489-e992-46ea-9fc7-317dfc206add";
        string resourceUrl = "https://devtreinamento.crm2.dynamics.com"; // Org URL  

        ClientCredential credentials = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
        var authContext = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext(authority);
        var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUrl, credentials);
        return result.AccessToken;
    }
```

My show token method:

```
[Route ("")]
    [HttpGet]
    public  ActionResult showToken()
    {
        var token = getToken.AccessTokenGenerator();

        return Ok(token);
    }
```

Comment: @Taniguchi.sales since it is already exposed over the internet, better change the secret on your end. Sadly SO has lot of mirror sites/scraping might have done already :)

Comment: thanks for telling me. i've cahanged the client secret

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your "Get" method to `async` and return a `Task<T>` of type T `ActionResult`, then `await` your call to `AccessTokenGenerator()`, in your current code, you are setting a variable equal to an `async` method without awaiting the `async` method to complete.:

```
[Route ("")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> showToken()
{
    var token = await getToken.AccessTokenGenerator();
    return Ok(token);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your asnwer it worked, getToken is the class that AccessTokenGenerator belongs.